# Hermiticity of spin-orbit coupling in real space

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators

In the [Kane-Mele model](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0411737), the spin-orbit coupling is defined in real space as

$$\sum_{\langle \langle i j \rangle \rangle \alpha \beta} i t_2 \nu_{ij} s^z_{\alpha \beta} c_{i \alpha}^\dagger c_{j \beta}$$

where the sum is over next-nearest-neighbor sites on a honeycomb lattice, and $\nu_{ij} = - \nu_{ij} = \pm 1$ depends on the orientation of the next-nearest-neighbor bonds (I don't believe the details of how $\nu_{ij}$ is calculated is relevant for Hermiticity). I am having difficulty understanding how this term is Hermitian. Taking the Hermitian conjugate seemingly gives

$$\left(\sum_{\langle \langle i j \rangle \rangle \alpha \beta} i t_2 \nu_{ij} s^z_{\alpha \beta} c_{i \alpha}^\dagger c_{j \beta}\right)^\dagger = \sum_{\langle \langle i j \rangle \rangle \alpha \beta} (-i) t_2 \nu_{ij} s^z_{\alpha \beta} c_{i \alpha} c_{j \beta}^\dagger = \sum_{\langle \langle i j \rangle \rangle \alpha \beta} i t_2 \nu_{ij} s^z_{\alpha \beta} c_{j \beta}^\dagger c_{i \alpha} 
\\
= -\sum_{\langle \langle i j \rangle \rangle \alpha \beta} i t_2 \nu_{ij} s^z_{\alpha \beta} c_{i \alpha}^\dagger c_{j \beta}  $$
where in the final line we have relabeled indices and used that $\nu_{ij} = - \nu_{ji}$, $s^z_{\alpha \beta} = s^z_{\beta \alpha}$.  I must be missing something obvious, but this seems to show that the term is anti-Hermitian, instead of Hermitian. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first expression after the equals sign on the first line you have $c_{i\alpha}c^\dagger_{j\beta}$. It should be   $c^\dagger_{j\beta}c_{i\alpha}$ since
$(AB)^\dagger = B^\dagger A^\dagger$.

Comment: Oh shoot, you're totally right. Thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

From the first to second expression on the first line, the Conjugation operation should transpose the matrix $v_{ij}$ to $v_{ji}$, giving the missing minus sign.